# How to setup hostnames using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, localhost, hostname, docker-compose

I have setup a few docker-containers with docker-compose.

When I start them via `docker-compose up` I can access them via their exposed ports, e.g. `localhost:9080` and `localhost:9180`.

I really would like to access them via hostnames, the `localhost:9180` should be accessable on my localhost via `api.local` and the `localhost:9080` via `webservice.local`

How can I achieve that? Is that something that `docker-compose` can do or do I have to use a reverse proxy on my localhost?

Currently my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
api:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "9180:80"
        - "9543:443"
    external_links:
        - mysql_mysql_1:mysql
    links:
        - booking-api

webservice:
    ports:
        - "9080:80"
        - "9443:433"
    image: registry.foo.bar:5000/webservice:latest
    volumes:
        - ~/.docker-history:/.bash_history
        - ~/.docker-bashrc:/.bashrc
        - ./:/var/www/virtual/webservice/current
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

`/etc/hosts` file resolves host-names only. Thus it can only resolve `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

If you add a line like
`api.local 127.0.0.1:9180` it wont work.

The only think you can do is to setup a reverse proxy (like nginx) on your host that listen to `api.local` and forwards the requests to `localhost:9180`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [dory](https://github.com/FreedomBen/dory) project.  By adding a `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable, the container becomes accessible by domain name.  For example, if you set `VIRTUAL_HOST=web.docker`, you can reach the container at `http://web.docker`.

The project home page has more info.  It's a young project but under active development.  Support for macOS is also planned now that Docker for Mac and dlite have emerged/matured.

Comment: as a followup, macOS support is implemented and working.